# Calculate mean for lists

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I want to calculate mean for lists of vectors. However received error message

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1293-04753fc36464> in <module>()
     13         else:
     14             NOT_FOUNT.append(j)
---> 15     Q_VEC.append(np.mean(DOC, axis=0))
     16     QUERY.append(WORD)
     17     #print(WORD, Q_VEC)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

My Code:

```
Q_VEC=[]
QUERY=[]
NOT_FOUNT=[]
for i in W_LIST:
    DOC=[]
    WORD=[]
    for j in i:
        if j in list(D_FINAL.keys()):
            DOC.append(D_FINAL[j])   #D_FINAL[j] is an array
            WORD.append(j)
        else:
            NOT_FOUNT.append(j)
    Q_VEC.append(np.mean(DOC, axis=0))
    QUERY.append(WORD)
```

The Data:

```
 W_LIST

 [['professional', 'training', None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None],
['undergraduate', 'management', None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None],
['professional', 'management', None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None]]

D_FINAL

{'professional': array([ -1.5453218 ,  
-2.9101162 ,  -1.7782371 ,  -0.7723548]),
'undergraduate': array([-5.044174  , 
-5.768703  ,  0.23328705,  1.6166878]),
'management': array([  0.9067916 ,  
-0.37680042,   2.2666857 ,  -1.3643779]),
'training': array([ -4343.5654  ,    
166.61334 ,  -4708.429   ,  11363.863])}
```

I want to calculate W_LIST's average, base on their vector value in D_FINAL.

"professional training" (will be saved to 'QUERY')vector value will be

```
[(-1.5453218)+(-4343.5654)/2,  (-2.9101162)+ 
(166.61334 )/2, (-1.7782371)+(-4708.429)/2, 
(-0.7723548)+(11363.863)/2]
```

The average vector will be saved to 'Q_VEC'

Thank you!

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception you should always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: i've added it, thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce the exception with your example data/code.  That error/exception happens when you do something like this: `a = np.arange(5); a[0] = [1,2,3]`.   [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite. Or just print the data right before the offending line.  That will give you a place to start.

Comment: Which version of Numpy are you using? I'm assuming `np` is Numpy.  I'm using 1.14.3.  Maybe try getting the newest version?

Comment: Try this: `Q_VEC.append(np.mean(np.array(DOC), axis=0))` . Maybe in your `numpy` version using a list of numpy arrays is what is behind this error.

Comment: @wwii my numpy version is same as you

Comment: @Jundiaius thanks but i got error message 
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-0c649b076534> in <module>()
     13         else:
     14             NOT_FOUNT.append(j)
---> 15     Q_VEC.append(np.mean(np.array(DOC), axis=0))
     16     QUERY.append(WORD)
     17     #print(WORD, Q_VEC)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.  (Sorry about the formatting, how do you make comments in code format? )

Answer (score 0):

I found elements in the dictionary are in different length, after fixing it, the issue was solved.